# Comparing Variances

Tags: probability

Which has the greater variance: rolling a standard six-sided die and summing that many standard eight-sided dice, or rolling a standard eight-sided die and summing that many six-sided dice?

This is a question that has stumped me, asked by a friend,

My original thoughts were that for the eight-sided case, that is rolling the six-sided dice and then rolling the eight-sided that many times and summing, that I could just multiply the expectation of the six-sided die and then multiply that by the variance of the eight-sided die? But this seems completely wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of finding variance of a sum of random number of independent and identically distributed random variables
$$Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N$$

The general solution for the problem is given by
$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\operatorname{E}[N]\operatorname{var}(X)+(\operatorname{E}[X])^2\operatorname{var}(N)$$

if $N$ is determined by the roll of 6-sided die then

$\operatorname{E}[N]=\frac{1+6}{2}=3.5$

$\operatorname{var}(N)=\frac{(6-1+1)^2-1}{12}=\frac{35}{12}$

$\operatorname{E}[X]=\frac{1+8}{2}=4.5$

$\operatorname{var}(X)=\frac{(8-1+1)^2-1}{12}=\frac{63}{12}$

and

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=3.5*\frac{63}{12}+(4.5)^2\frac{35}{12}=77.4375$$

and if $N$ is determined by the roll of 8-sided die

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=4.5*\frac{35}{12}+(3.5)^2\frac{63}{12}=77.4375$$

More generally, for the case of $n-$ and $m-$ sided dice, the variance is equal to

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\frac{n+1}{2}\frac{m^2-1}{12}+\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^2\frac{n^2-1}{12}$$

and after little algebra

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\frac{(n+1)(m+1)}{48}(mn+n+m-3)$$

you can see that $n$ and $m$ enter symmetrically, so the variances are always the same.

Comment: I am not familiar with this formula - could you please point out where I may find it?

Comment: @HughEntwistle - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojHUL91qksU

Answer (score 1):

It is the same... exactly the same.

one 6 sided die:

$\mu_6 = \sum_\limits{i=1}^6 \frac {1}{6} i = \frac {7}{2}\\
\sigma_6^2 = \sum_\limits{i=1}^6 \frac {1}{6}i^2 - \mu^2 = \frac 16(\frac 16 (6\cdot 7 \cdot 13)) - (\frac 72)^2\\
\frac {91}{6} - \frac{49}{4} = \frac {35}{12}$

mulitple dice:

The mean of n dice is n times the mean of 1 die
The variance of n dice is two times the variance of n die.

But what I really want to know is what is

$\sum_\limits{i=n}^{6n} p_n(i) i^2$

Where $p_n(i)$ is the probability of rolling $i$ on $n$ dice.

$\sum_\limits{i=n}^{6n} p_n(i) i^2 - n^2\mu_6^2 = n\sigma_6^2\\
\sum_\limits{i=n}^{6n} p_n(i) i^2 = n\sigma_6^2 + n^2\mu_6^2$

d8 d6

mean = $\sum_\limits{i=1}{8} \frac 18 \mu_6 = \frac {9}{2} \mu_6 = \frac {63}{4}$

Variance

$\frac 18 \sum_\limits{n=1}^8 \sum_\limits{i=n}^{6n} p_n(i) i^2 - (\frac {63}{4})^2\\
\frac 18 \sum_\limits{n=1}^8 n\sigma_6^2 + n^2\mu_6^2  - (\frac {9}{2}\mu_6)^2\\
\frac {9}{2}\sigma_6^2 + \frac {17\cdot 9\cdot 8}{8\cdot 6}\mu_6^2  - (\frac {9}{2}\mu_6)^2\\
\frac {9}{2}\sigma_6^2 + 5.25\mu_6^2\\
\frac {9}{2} \frac {35}{12} + \frac{21}{4}(\frac 72)^2 = 77.4375\\
$

8 sided dice
$\mu_8 = \frac {9}{2}\\
\sigma_8 = \frac {17\cdot9\cdot8}{8\cdot 6} -\frac {81}{4} = \frac {21}{4}$

d6 d8

mean = $\sum_\limits{i=1}{6} \frac 16 \mu_8 = \frac {7}{2} \mu_6 = \frac {63}{4}$

Variance

$\frac 16 \sum_\limits{n=1}^6 \sum_\limits{i=n}^{8n} p_n(i) i^2 - (\frac {63}{4})^2\\
\frac 16 \sum_\limits{n=1}^8 n\sigma_8^2 + n^2\mu_8^2  - (\frac {7}{2}\mu_8)^2\\
\frac {7}{2}\sigma_8^2 + \frac {13\cdot 7\cdot 6}{6\cdot 6}\mu_8^2  - (\frac {7}{2}\mu_8)^2\\
\frac {7}{2}\sigma_8^2 + \frac{35}{12}\mu_8^2\\
\frac {7}{2}\frac {21}{4} + \frac{35}{12}(\frac 92)^2 = 77.4375\\
$